# Desktop through Emulator's camera

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-virtual-device

I want to be able to take pictures of my desktop through the Android emulator's camera? Somebody knows the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest mirroring of your android device using Airdroid or Vysor.
I understand it is not the exact solution but it works .

Answer (score 0):

Tools > AVD Manager > Emulator select > Edit this emulator > Show Advanced Settings > Camera - Front - Select Webcam0

[as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTCWt.jpg)